# Nested Classes in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, object-oriented

I wondered how nested classes in C# work as I often use them when I write native C# code (like `Woods.Tree.Add(new Tree).Leaf.Color`) so i tried it by my self with a Navigation example. There is a Position integer which declares a point on a line. To move left the position will be subtracted by 1, to move right the position will added by 1.

I think its quite pedantic and much code to write for such a 'simple' task. Is this the right way or is there an easier, smaller way to archive this?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NestedTest nt = new NestedTest();//create test
            nt.Navigate.Left();
            Console.WriteLine(nt.Position);
            nt.Navigate.Left();
            nt.Navigate.Left();
            Console.WriteLine(nt.Position);
            nt.Navigate.Rigth();
            Console.WriteLine(nt.Position);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
    class NestedTest
    {
        public int Position { get; private set; }
        public NavigateClass Navigate;//create the NavigateClass in NestedTest

        //Nested NavigateClass
        public class NavigateClass
        {
            private NestedTest _o;//the placeholder
            public NavigateClass(NestedTest obj)
            {
                _o = obj;//Set the NestedTest class so we know which Position we have to navigate trough.
            }
            public void Left()
            {
                Console.Write("<-");
                _o.Position--;//Move Position to the left (-1)
            }

            public void Rigth()
            {
                Console.Write("->");
                _o.Position++;//Move Position to the right (+1)
            }
        }

        public NestedTest(int num = 10)
        {
            this.Position = num;//Set start position
            Navigate = new NavigateClass(this);//Set the _o in Navigate so it knows which Position it has to navigate trough
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this the right way or is there an easier, smaller way to archive this?

It depends on how you define *the right way*. Is your goal short and small code or is your goal testability and maintainability? These two goals are mutualy exclusive.

---

If you want to have it short then of course there is a way. You don't need the nested class at all.

```
class NestedTest
{
    public int Position { get; private set; }

    public void Left()
    {
        Console.Write("<-");
        Position--;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to have maintainable code then you need to write more code and correctly use dependency injection and possibly use a few interfaces as abstractions. Nested public classes are a bad style anyway so you should avoid them.

This is how such an implementation could look like. The `NestedTest` gets an interface that allows accesing its `Position`. Its constructor also requries a lambda that lets you specify the navigator for this instance.

```
public interface IPositionable
{
    int Position { get; set; }
}

class NestedTest : IPositionable
{
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public INavigator Navigator { get; }

    public NestedTest(int num, Func<IPositionable, INavigator> createNavigator)
    {
        Position = num;
        Navigator = createNavigator(this);
    }
}
```

Where the `Navigator` is now also abstracted by an interface and can be faked for testing or exachnged for another navigator later:

```
public interface INavigator
{
    void Left();
}

public class Navigator : INavigator
{
    private IPositionable _positionable;

    public Navigator(IPositionable positionable)
    {
        _positionable = positionable;
    }

    public void Left()
    {
        _positionable.Position--;
    }
}
```

---

It's up to you to decide. Shortest code possible or testable and maintainable?

Comment: Okay, so my idea was correct to pass the outer class to the inner class, and this is the way you do it in C#, right? Thanks for the example with the interfaces

Comment: @MaxR. yes, in general the idea was ok but using a nested class not so much. Usually it's better to use abstractions if you are going to extend or test it later.